# Running two modals works runnig a third one in a different bootstrap tab does not

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I am using django-bootstrap-modal-forms. I have bootstrap tabs with crispy forms I made a modal for files and it worked; But I am trying to add two modals; one for authors the other for translators.
Ill show the code that is loaded in a table.

```
{% include "_modal.html" %}
<div id="linkeddocuments">
<div class="col-12 mb-3">
    {% include "_authors_table.html" %}
</div>
</div>
<div id="searchdocumentpanel" class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col"></div>
   <div class="col">
   <button type="button" class='btn btn-primary btn-danger' id='create-author-async'><span class="fa fa-plus mr-2"></span>new author async</button>
    <br/>
    <br/>Search Authors:<br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" id="id_search_authors">
    </input>
    </div>
    <div class="col"></div>
</div>
  <br/>
  <div class="col-12 mb-3">
      {% include "_authors_candidates_table.html" %}
  </div>
</div>

<div id="linkeddocuments">
<div class="col-12 mb-3">
    {% include "_translators_table.html" %}
</div>
</div>
<div id="searchdocumentpanel" class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col"></div>
   <div class="col">
   <button type="button" class='btn btn-primary btn-danger' id='create-translator-async'><span class="fa fa-plus mr-2"></span>new translator async</button>
    <br/>
    <br/>Search Translator:<br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" id="id_search_translators">
    </input>
    </div>
    <div class="col"></div>
</div>
  <br/>
  <div class="col-12 mb-3">
      {% include "_translators_candidates_table.html" %}
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
var asyncSuccessMessageCreateAuthor = [
"<div ",
"style='position:fixed;top:0;z-index:10000;width:100%;border-radius:0;' ",
"class='alert alert-icon alert-success alert-dismissible fade show mb-0' role='alert'>",
"Success: Author was created.",
"<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'>",
"<span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>",
"</button>",
"</div>",
"<script>",
"$('.alert').fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function () {$('.alert').slideUp(500).remove();});",
"<\/script>"
].join("");

var asyncSuccessMessageUpdateAuthor = [
"<div ",
"style='position:fixed;top:0;z-index:10000;width:100%;border-radius:0;' ",
"class='alert alert-icon alert-success alert-dismissible fade show mb-0' role='alert'>",
"Success: Author was updated.",
"<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'>",
"<span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>",
"</button>",
"</div>",
"<script>",
"$('.alert').fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function () {$('.alert').slideUp(500).remove();});",
"<\/script>"
].join("");
var asyncSuccessMessageCreateTranslator = [
"<div ",
"style='position:fixed;top:0;z-index:10000;width:100%;border-radius:0;' ",
"class='alert alert-icon alert-success alert-dismissible fade show mb-0' role='alert'>",
"Success: Translator was created.",
"<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'>",
"<span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>",
"</button>",
"</div>",
"<script>",
"$('.alert').fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function () {$('.alert').slideUp(500).remove();});",
"<\/script>"
].join("");

var asyncSuccessMessageUpdateTranslator = [
"<div ",
"style='position:fixed;top:0;z-index:10000;width:100%;border-radius:0;' ",
"class='alert alert-icon alert-success alert-dismissible fade show mb-0' role='alert'>",
"Success: Translator was updated.",
"<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'>",
"<span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>",
"</button>",
"</div>",
"<script>",
"$('.alert').fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function () {$('.alert').slideUp(500).remove();});",
"<\/script>"
].join("");

function updateAuthorModalForm() {
$(".author-edit").each(function () {
  $(this).modalForm({
    formURL: $(this).data("form-url"),
    asyncUpdate: true,
    asyncSettings: {
      closeOnSubmit: false,
      successMessage: asyncSuccessMessageUpdateAuthor,
      dataUrl: "{% url 'authors' publication.pk %}",
      dataElementId: "#authors-div",
      dataKey: "table",
      addModalFormFunction: updateAuthorModalForm
    }
  });
});
}
updateAuthorModalForm();
function updateTranslatorModalForm() {
$(".translator-edit").each(function () {
  $(this).modalForm({
    formURL: $(this).data("form-url"),
    asyncUpdate: true,
    asyncSettings: {
      closeOnSubmit: false,
      successMessage: asyncSuccessMessageUpdateTranslator,
      dataUrl: "{% url 'translators' publication.pk %}",
      dataElementId: "#translators-div",
      dataKey: "table",
      addModalFormFunction: updateTranslatorModalForm
    }
  });
});
}
updateTranslatorModalForm();
function createAuthorAsyncModalForm() {
$("#create-author-async").modalForm({
    formURL: "{% url 'author_new' publication.pk %}",
    modalID: "#create-modal",
    asyncUpdate: true,
    createAuthor: true,
    asyncSettings: {
      closeOnSubmit: true,
      successMessage: asyncSuccessMessageCreateAuthor,
      dataUrl: "{% url 'authors' publication.pk %}",
      dataElementId: "#authors-div",
      dataKey: "table",
      addModalFormFunction: updateAuthorModalForm
     }
});
}
createAuthorAsyncModalForm();
function createTranslatorAsyncModalForm() {
$("#create-translator-async").modalForm({
    formURL: "{% url 'translator_new' publication.pk %}",
    modalID: "#create-modal",
    asyncUpdate: true,
    asyncSettings: {
      closeOnSubmit: true,
      successMessage: asyncSuccessMessageCreateTranslator,
      dataUrl: "{% url 'translators' publication.pk %}",
      dataElementId: "#translatros-div",
      dataKey: "table",
      addModalFormFunction: updateTranslatorModalForm
     }
});
}
createTranslatorAsyncModalForm();
// Hide message
$(".alert").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function () {
  $(".alert").slideUp(500);
});
});
</script>
```

And for the files:

```
{% include "_modal.html" %}
<div id="linkeddocuments">
<div class="col-12 mb-3">
    {% include "_authors_table.html" %}
</div>
</div>
<div id="searchdocumentpanel" class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col"></div>
   <div class="col">
   <button type="button" class='btn btn-primary btn-danger' id='create-author-async'><span class="fa fa-plus mr-2"></span>new author async</button>
    <br/>
    <br/>Search Authors:<br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" id="id_search_authors">
    </input>
    </div>
    <div class="col"></div>
</div>
  <br/>
  <div class="col-12 mb-3">
      {% include "_authors_candidates_table.html" %}
  </div>
</div>

<div id="linkeddocuments">
<div class="col-12 mb-3">
    {% include "_translators_table.html" %}
</div>
</div>
<div id="searchdocumentpanel" class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col"></div>
   <div class="col">
   <button type="button" class='btn btn-primary btn-danger' id='create-translator-async'><span class="fa fa-plus mr-2"></span>new translator async</button>
    <br/>
    <br/>Search Translator:<br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" id="id_search_translators">
    </input>
    </div>
    <div class="col"></div>
</div>
  <br/>
  <div class="col-12 mb-3">
      {% include "_translators_candidates_table.html" %}
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
var asyncSuccessMessageCreateAuthor = [
"<div ",
"style='position:fixed;top:0;z-index:10000;width:100%;border-radius:0;' ",
"class='alert alert-icon alert-success alert-dismissible fade show mb-0' role='alert'>",
"Success: Author was created.",
"<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'>",
"<span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>",
"</button>",
"</div>",
"<script>",
"$('.alert').fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function () {$('.alert').slideUp(500).remove();});",
"<\/script>"
].join("");

var asyncSuccessMessageUpdateAuthor = [
"<div ",
"style='position:fixed;top:0;z-index:10000;width:100%;border-radius:0;' ",
"class='alert alert-icon alert-success alert-dismissible fade show mb-0' role='alert'>",
"Success: Author was updated.",
"<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'>",
"<span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>",
"</button>",
"</div>",
"<script>",
"$('.alert').fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function () {$('.alert').slideUp(500).remove();});",
"<\/script>"
].join("");
var asyncSuccessMessageCreateTranslator = [
"<div ",
"style='position:fixed;top:0;z-index:10000;width:100%;border-radius:0;' ",
"class='alert alert-icon alert-success alert-dismissible fade show mb-0' role='alert'>",
"Success: Translator was created.",
"<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'>",
"<span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>",
"</button>",
"</div>",
"<script>",
"$('.alert').fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function () {$('.alert').slideUp(500).remove();});",
"<\/script>"
].join("");

var asyncSuccessMessageUpdateTranslator = [
"<div ",
"style='position:fixed;top:0;z-index:10000;width:100%;border-radius:0;' ",
"class='alert alert-icon alert-success alert-dismissible fade show mb-0' role='alert'>",
"Success: Translator was updated.",
"<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'>",
"<span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>",
"</button>",
"</div>",
"<script>",
"$('.alert').fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function () {$('.alert').slideUp(500).remove();});",
"<\/script>"
].join("");

function updateAuthorModalForm() {
$(".author-edit").each(function () {
  $(this).modalForm({
    formURL: $(this).data("form-url"),
    asyncUpdate: true,
    asyncSettings: {
      closeOnSubmit: false,
      successMessage: asyncSuccessMessageUpdateAuthor,
      dataUrl: "{% url 'authors' publication.pk %}",
      dataElementId: "#authors-div",
      dataKey: "table",
      addModalFormFunction: updateAuthorModalForm
    }
  });
});
}
updateAuthorModalForm();
function updateTranslatorModalForm() {
$(".translator-edit").each(function () {
  $(this).modalForm({
    formURL: $(this).data("form-url"),
    asyncUpdate: true,
    asyncSettings: {
      closeOnSubmit: false,
      successMessage: asyncSuccessMessageUpdateTranslator,
      dataUrl: "{% url 'translators' publication.pk %}",
      dataElementId: "#translators-div",
      dataKey: "table",
      addModalFormFunction: updateTranslatorModalForm
    }
  });
});
}
updateTranslatorModalForm();
function createAuthorAsyncModalForm() {
$("#create-author-async").modalForm({
    formURL: "{% url 'author_new' publication.pk %}",
    modalID: "#create-modal",
    asyncUpdate: true,
    createAuthor: true,
    asyncSettings: {
      closeOnSubmit: true,
      successMessage: asyncSuccessMessageCreateAuthor,
      dataUrl: "{% url 'authors' publication.pk %}",
      dataElementId: "#authors-div",
      dataKey: "table",
      addModalFormFunction: updateAuthorModalForm
     }
});
}
createAuthorAsyncModalForm();
function createTranslatorAsyncModalForm() {
$("#create-translator-async").modalForm({
    formURL: "{% url 'translator_new' publication.pk %}",
    modalID: "#create-modal",
    asyncUpdate: true,
    asyncSettings: {
      closeOnSubmit: true,
      successMessage: asyncSuccessMessageCreateTranslator,
      dataUrl: "{% url 'translators' publication.pk %}",
      dataElementId: "#translatros-div",
      dataKey: "table",
      addModalFormFunction: updateTranslatorModalForm
     }
});
}
createTranslatorAsyncModalForm();
// Hide message
$(".alert").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function () {
  $(".alert").slideUp(500);
});
});
</script>
```

If I disable the first two modals (authors & translators) the file modal will work. Otherwise I get a dark screen without modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by creating a new _modal2.html and use id create-modal2. Each tab has its own create modal. Was a html problem.